# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' working with a github clone

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to re-run the code made available here : https://github.com/HanssonMagnus/scrape_bis

I'm able to run the 2 first steps. However, when I try to run the command for the 3rd step

```
cd source/0_scrape_bis
python main.py
```

I obtain the following error :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

When I do `pipenv graph`, I can see that beautifulsoup4 has been installed as a dependencies of textract.

Does anyone know what I can do to make it works ?

Thank you for your help